# Порядок записи координат в Яндекс.Карты API

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты, yandex-geocoding-api

Пытаюсь повторить пример из песочницы: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/delivery_zones
Но, при полном повторении, вместо Санкт-Петербурга прямоугольники отрисовываются в районе Ирана - порядок чтения координат почему-то другой. То же самое происходит, если я выгружаю карту из Конструктора карт - в файле координаты формата [долгота, широта], но api воспринимает их наоборот. В документации нашел только про HTTP-запросы на геокодирование: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/concepts/input_params-docpage/ но это применимо только к конкретным запросам.
В связи с этим возникает вопрос: есть ли способ поменять порядок считывания координат? Или, в крайнем случае, как быстро поменять координаты местами в geojson?

Comment: к сожалению это общая проблема картографических сервисов, большинство зарубежных lon,lat у нас например гиспанораме наоборот

Comment: https://github.com/eivinhb/geojson-flip#readme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно поменять порядок координат в подключении апи с помощью параметра coordorder:

```
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;coordorder=longlat&amp;apikey=<ваш API-ключ>"></script>
```

Документация: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/load-docpage/#load__param